# What does it mean to "install" a language on your machine?

Tags: programming-languages, installation

So I'm starting out with a few languages and had some php and JavaScript knowledge, but Ive always used php with WP only. I'm starting to learn python and php (off Wordpress) and the first thing I read everywhere is to "install" python on your machine to work with it.

I have installed the python launcher directly from python.org but not sure what exactly it does or what it's there for. It's a very basic question but what does it mean to install python or php etc on your computer to develop for that langague?

Thanks in advance ladies & gents!

**UPDATE:** I think I got it now! Thank you everyone for the detailed responses and help! It's MUCH appreciated! :)

Comment: It means installing the compiler or interpreter of the language. Sometimes even it's libraries.

Answer (score 2):

"Installing" a language can mean different things. Typically, you have to download a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) for a compiled language, or for an interpreted language, like Java, you need an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) as well (the Java Virtual Machine). These can typically come pre-packaged in an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), or editor, which allows you to write the code.

If these terms confuse you, I suggest you read up a bit on compilation (conversion to bytecode) of programming languages. It will help you better understand how the high-level language you write in gets fed to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

Programming languages are made up of a few components:

- **the language definition** -- usually a document that describes the language syntax and semantics
- **the language implementation** -- a program that executes statements in the language, producing output, typically a compiler and runtime library, or an interpreter.
- **the language libraries** -- helper modules with common functionality

To install a "language" means to install an implementation of the language. This means installing the compiler or interpreter, and the most common libraries. Once installed your can write and execute programs in that language , locally on your machine.

This is the case for all languages -- unless you already have the implementation installed for you by your operating system manager (as often C; Ruby; Objective C are) or web browser (for the case of JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

I can see it being a bit confusing, as 'Python' can mean 2 different things depending upon context.  If you are talking about the language, 'Python' is the set of commands defined in the language spec.  However, 'Python' can also be a shorthand for 'the Python interpreter, core libraries, and other tools'.  When people talk about 'installing Python', they mean installing these components on a system.  These components are what allow you to actually run Python code.  Otherwise, it's just a bunch of text in a file.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms - it means to download the language's interpreter that is appropriate for your operating system. The interpreter is the program that understands the code that you write and executes it.

In the case of Python it is simpler as osx and Linux both come with Python as part of their default installations.

For Windows, you should download the [official Windows installer](http://www.python.org/download/) for Python. Installing it is just like installing any other Windows program.

Similarly, for PHP you can download the [official installer for Windows](http://windows.php.net/download/).

Comment: It could be a compiler; or a compiler and interpreter; and libraries.

Comment: You are right Don but since the OP specifically mentioned PHP and Python, I thought a simpler answer would be better.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Python the language is actually tied to a compiler that was developed with it. I installed it and it comes with both a console and GUI to execute script in. For PHP, I know PHP has a console that's installed when you install a server that you can access and change PHP configuration settings. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

When you use PHP on a web host they have already installed two programs:

- A web server (e.g Apache)
- A php interpreter

The web server will get a request, ask PHP to execute a program. The program 
is the php page you have written. 
The PHP interpreter executes the program which produces an output which is then sent back to 
the client by the web server.

When you develop a program on your own computer the setting is different.

First, except for web development, you wont have a web server running on your machine which tells an interpreter to run your program, you will have to run the interpreter yourself.

Typically you use a command line shell (e.g. cmd.exe) on windows.

```
C:>python script.py
```

When cmd.exe executes this command it looks for a program "python.exe" and tells it to run your program "script.py". By default the output of script.py is sent to cmd.exe which then just displays it in its window.

In order for this to succeed there must be a python.exe installed on your computer, so first you have to install a program "python.exe" called the python interpreter.

This is the story on how to *run* your python program on your machine.
Developing also involves *writing* the script.

To write your program "script.py" you could theoretically just use a simple text editor like Notepad on windows and then execute the script as described above. But this is not convenient even for very short programs.

Fortunately when you Install the Python interpreter it will also install some additional programs, one of them IDLE which is an editor for python programs good enough to write simple python programs. 
For your convenience IDLE can also directly tell python.exe to run your sript without you having to type the command in cmd.exe.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is JUST The detail I was looking for and it's not making sense in my logical brain ;)

Comment: Could you please upvote the answers you like and if your question is answered by my answer (or another) accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask